# Does SOSL wildcard (*) work with space characters

Tags: sosl, dynamic-sosl

I am currently trying to implement a sosl search query, so I can filter out non-letter characters for searching inside the salesforce database. Everything works as expected, however when I encounter a space character in the inputted data, I replace it with a wildcard for searching e.g.

```
FIND {"Ab" AND "cd*ef"} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Candidate__c(Firstname__c, Lastname__c)
```

I would expect to get the following candidate;

Firstname__c: Ab

Lastname__c: cd ef

However I am not receiving any result from my searchquery. With following query, the correct candidate is returned;

```
FIND {"Ab" AND "cd ef"} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Candidate__c(Firstname__c, Lastname__c)
```

Is this expected behaviour for the wildcards in a SOSL query and are there any workarounds? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is not explicitly documented, but going through the documentation, it seems that you cannot expect a *space character* to be included in a wildcard search viz., `cd*ef`. From the excerpt as below from [this documentation on wildcard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm), it seems the *middle or end of your search term* necessarily expects a single word with no space.

> Asterisks match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your search term. For example, a search for *john** finds items that start with *john*, such as, *john*, *johnson*, or *johnny*.

Later in the same [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm), it does cover the *space character*.

> A search for *mi* meyers* finds items with *mike meyers* or *michael meyers*.

So in your case if you want to search for `cd ef` with a wildcard, you can have the search term defined as `cd* ef` (with a space between `*` and the character `e`).